# format substring of result from formula

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to format (using bold, italic, colors etc.) certain substrings of the result from a formula in a cell?

When I have a "fixed" string in a cell I can easily use (quite genetic:) TargetCell.characters(position, length).property = value
to get the chosen property in the substring working.

I've tried to do the same thing with the result (which is a string) without succes. Is it possible?

The result from the formula in a cell could show something like:

```
1:4%|2:45%|3:5%
```

But I want to the cell to show something like:

```
1:__4%__|2:__45%__|3:__5%__  ' (the percentage in bold)
```

Is there any means to achieve this. (SORRY! It's not showing with bold on this homepage, maybe because of the percent sign ... but the __ is meaning in bold!)
Thanks

Comment: No, it is not possible. You can only do that with a string.

Comment: If you really need this then you can (for example) hide the calculated column and use VBA to make a formatted copy of the calculated results.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld. Good. Clear answer! I can stop my tryings!
and Tim Williams. I'd thought about it in the lines of your proposal, but wanted to see if my question really had a positive answer.